# url encryption with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to encrypt  `assignment_id` in url which retrived on **ajax** table

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/Welcome/quotation_detailed?assignment_id='+data[i].assignment_id+'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm item_edit" data-assignment_id="'+data[i].assignment_id+'">'+data[i].assignment_id+'</a>
```

Comment: You should probably encrypt the id on the server side. Encrypting a value locally after sending it in plain text to the client is not securing anything.

Comment: yeah but the id is auto increment values how can i encrypt it on server side?

Comment: First of all, please format your code properly. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks (And your own words explaining the problem as well, those are _not_ code, but you have currently formatted them as such.)

Comment: _Why_ do you want to “encrypt” this value, what exactly do you expect to achieve by that?

Comment: i m using base64 like this: <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>Admin/assignments_detailed?assignment_id=<?php echo base64_encode($row->assignment_id) ?>"><?php echo $row->assignment_id; ?></a>

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed possibilities to achieve what you want - here is a step by step guide

1. Read the docs - CI provides an **encryption** library - take a look [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html) - and define the generated key as described in your config.php
2. create a helper in your `application/helpers` folder, call it `encryption_helper.php` and put the following functions in

   ```
   function ci_encode($str_to_encode) {
       $CI = get_instance();

       if (!empty($str_to_encode)) {
           return bin2hex($CI->encryption->encrypt($str_to_encode));
       }
       return $str_to_encode;
   }

   function ci_decode($str_to_decode) {
       $CI = get_instance();
       return $CI->encryption->decrypt(pack('H*', $str_to_decode));
   }
   ```
3. Go to your autoload.php in your application/config folder and autoload the library and the helper.
   Something like `$autoload['libraries'] = array(...,'encryption');` and `$autoload['helper'] = array(...,'encryption_helper');` should work
4. now you can encode / decode whatever you want - based on your example:

   ```
   <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>Admin/assignments_detailed?assignment_id=<?php echo ci_encode($row->assignment_id) ?>"><?php echo $row->assignment_id; ?></a>
   ```

   and decoding

   ```
   echo ci_decode($this->input->get('assignment_id');
   ```

> But keep in mind - the main problem is that you try to obfuscate some
>   information which should never be obfuscated - in the end it is your
>   responsibility to handle data properly - even if some user tries to
>   manipulate it

Comment: Yeah but the problem is when i get data in ajax table, php code is not working:assignment_id='+data[i].assignment_id+'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm item_edit" data-assignment_id="'+data[i].assignment_id+'">'+data[i].assignment_id+'</a>

Comment: naaa - you should clarify what you are doing - post sample codes in order to understand what you are doing - because there is no way that my offered option doesn't work

Comment: i want assignment_id='**+data[i].assignment_id+**' in encrypted form

Comment: yeah and where is assignment_id coming from ?

Comment: From database i was previously doing what you suggest with base64_encode method but it's not working with ajax

Comment: obviously it is coming from the database, but how is it getting from the database to the view? if ajax is populating a table or whatever is displaying this then you need to target that by encrypting the values *before* they get to the view or in the case of ajax, before the response. you should never try and apply any encryption in js as the plaintext value is clearly visible to anyone with some knowledge of dev tools. further, base64 is **easily** decrypted: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php.

Comment: sintakonte has given you the tools to achieve what you desire, unfortunately, you didn't give enough information to start with.

Comment: Yeah, i try sintakonte's steps:                                                                        `public function test1()
 {
  $data="Hello";
  echo ci_encode($data);
 }`

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>Admin/assignments_detailed?assignment_id=<?php echo ci_encode($row->assignment_id) ?>"><?php echo $row->assignment_id; ?></a>` i want this in `'<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/Welcome/assignments_detailed?assignment_id='+data[i].assignment_id+'" data product_code="'+data[i].assignment_id+'">'+data[i].assignment_id+'</a>'+` in this code

Comment: you dont get it right ? - provide your controller who prepares this data, which are sent to your ajax function - you only post some javascript code which is irrelevant...

Comment: `public function getRequested()
 {
  $student_id=$this->session->userdata('student_id');
  $data=$this->MyModel->getRequestedAssignments($student_id);
  echo json_encode($data);
 }`

Comment: Model:
 `public function getRequestedAssignments($student_id)
   {
    $status="0";
    $this->db->where('student_id',$student_id);
    $this->db->where('status',$status);
    $result=$this->db->get('assignment_mst');
    return $result->result();
   }`

Comment: Actually, i retrived those data in Ajax table and when someone clicks on assignment id there is page which shows detailed assignment. But i want assignment id to be encrypted when it goes to detailed page, i get that without ajax in <a></a> tag but problem is with Ajax

Comment: dude - how often do i've to explain - i don't care about your JS - i need the controller where those data are sent to your ajax script - you say - you retrieve this data - but from where ? i guess from one of your  controllers - and this is exact the code which is necessary...

Answer (score 0):

```
'<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/Welcome/quotation_detailed?assignment_id='+window.btoa(data[i].assignment_id)+'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm item_edit" data-assignment_id="'+data[i].assignment_id+'">'+data[i].assignment_id+'</a>'
```

I did it by base64_encode in javascript